# I need help on some problems of geometry . How do I find the missing length on a triangle side

Tags: geometry

[This](http://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mathwarehouse.com%2Fgeometry%2Ftriangles%2Fimages%2Fright-triangles%2F3-4-5-right-triangles%2F3-4-5-triangle_problem1.png&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mathwarehouse.com%2Fgeometry%2Ftriangles%2Fright-triangle.php&h=235&w=219&tbnid=1mM4DXIyX_XCqM%3A&zoom=1&docid=V12jCcA8YPZVnM&ei=fnqXU76VJsqJqgb674DQCw&tbm=isch&ved=0CDIQMygHMAc&iact=rc&uact=3&dur=625&page=1&start=0&ndsp=20) is what the triangle looks like, I need help finding the missing number which is right now replaced by 'x'

Comment: Have you learned about Pythagoras' theorem?

Answer (score 1):

We have: $x^2 = 6^2 + 8^2$. You can take it from here.